# Start a fragmentActivity from activity using intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have a main activity .In which i have some action button. I want when i press one button then a new activity will start which contain two fragment.But when i click on the button it give me error fore close. I am navigating from activity to another activity through intents. this is my intent code

```
if(v.getId()==R.id.Search)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Search.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Here Is My Log File

```
12-04 09:32:43.501: E/Trace(768): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.student_managment/com.example.student_managment.Search}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.example.student_managment.Search.onCreate(Search.java:13)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  ... 11 more
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.student_managment.Lower_frag cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:388)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:363)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:264)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  ... 21 more
```

Comment: did you added the activity name to your manifest??

Comment: yes i have added serach activity in the manifest..Search activity is basically extended from FragmentActivity

Comment: Would you please tell me how to copy from log...I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: select the full error log and press ctrl + C.. Then paste it here

Comment: 12-04 09:32:43.501: E/Trace(768): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 09:32:46.812: E/AndroidRuntime(768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.student_managment/com.example.student_managment.Search}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: no... paste it with your question..

Comment: You don't use the right imports. Make sure your `Lower_frag` class extends the `Fragment` class from the compatibility package and **not** the SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.student_managment.Lower_frag cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment` which means you probably declared a fragment (in your xml layout inflated in your Search.class) which isn't a fragment. Check the layout inflated in your Search.class